# MongoDB: Failed to Connect to a LAN mongodb replica set

Tags: mongodb

I have a replica set mongodb server on WSL2 of WindowsPC1, IP:192.168.10.108
Then I connect it on another WindowsPC2 using MongoDB Compass, IP:192.168.10.106

The following connection string works:

```bash
mongodb://admin:xxxxxx@192.168.10.108:27017/?directConnection=true
```

But the following connection string does not work: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

```bash
mongodb://admin:xxxxx@192.168.10.108:27017,192.168.10.108:27018,192.168.10.108:27019/?replicaSet=rs0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&readPreference=secondary
```

Any one can help me?

I tried using mongosh of PC2'WSL2 to connect, and it worked:

```bash
$ mongosh --host 192.168.10.108
```

But the following command still did not work:

```
$ mongosh "mongodb://admin:xxxxx@192.168.10.108:27017,192.168.10.108:27018,192.168.10.108:27019/?replicaSet=rs0&retryWrites=true&w=majority&readPreference=secondary"
```

Error message: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

---

---

Update:

The problem is resolved!
The previous bad replica set config

```js
var oldConf = rs.conf()
/*
{
members:[{
host: 'localhost:27017'
},{
host: 'localhost:27018'
},{
host: 'localhost:27019'
}]
}
*/
```

Then fix it with right config:

```js
oldConf.members[0].host = 'xxx.ronnie:27017'
oldConf.members[1].host = 'xxx.ronnie:27018'
oldConf.members[2].host = 'xxx.ronnie:27019'
rs.reconfig(oldConf)
```

`xxx.ronnie` is LAN hostname.

Comment: Did you initiate the Replica Set?

Comment: Yes, I did.

In the server PC1:

```bash
$ mongosh "mongodb://admin:xxxx@127.0.0.1:27017,127.0.0.1:27018,xxxxx"

rs0 [primary] test> rs.status()

{
    set: "rs0",
    ....
    members:[{
        _id: 0,
        name: "localhost:27017",
        stateStr: "PRIMARY"
    },{
        _id: 1,
        name: "localhost:27018",
        stateStr: "SECONDARY"
    },{
        _id: 2,
        name: "localhost:27018",
        stateStr: "SECONDARY"
    }]
}
```

Comment: This does not work. You must initiate the replica set with real IP addresses (i.e. 192.168.10.108) or even better with hostname (as recommended by MongoDB). Apart from that, you have two members `localhost:27018` - this will fail anyway. And you should put such additional information as edit to your question instead of putting it into a comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
The probolem is resolved!
I reconfig replicaset with hostname instead of 'localhost'.